# jquery ajax process success then continue load html code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to make. jquery ajax success, then continue load page's html?

For explain: I need when open the page. fist loading `css, js` code. then loading near the jquery ajax code, make a stop. stay the jquery ajax data poccess finished, then continue loading the `<body>` code. show `<div id="data"></div>` and other `html` code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    url: "pageb.php", 
    dataType: "html",
    type: 'POST', 
    data: "value="+ value, 
    success: function(data){ 
        //stop open page, after data back success, then continue loading the html code.
        $("#data").html(data);        
        }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="data"></div>
...
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the whole page is loaded via AJAX, there is no way to tell the browser "Ehi, wait rendeering the page until I say so".

Comment: Sure there is. `<body style="display:none">` `$(document).ready(function() { $('body').show(); }` (with the JS placed within a script tag of course). I wouldn't really recommend this approach however.

Answer (score 1):

If you want that way , you should go for **async:false** as others suggested.

But async:false will block the page , but if you want that way its fine.

But if you have time try this plugin , nice one

http://jquery.malsup.com/block/

Answer (score 0):

Well the idea of AJAX is that it's asynchronous so it does not care about what everything else on the page is doing/what is being loaded, etc. Try setting `async:false` in your `$.ajax()` params and see what happens.